# pg_basebackup: error: could not initiate base backup: ERROR: could not stat file or directory

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres 14 running on Windows 2019 server and I am using pg_basebackup to take regular backups.

The same powershell script which was working last week suddenly started giving me below errors.
No changes happened in the system except a host reboot.

For testing purposes, I tried giving full access to everyone to the both data directory/backup directory and still the same error.

```
PS G:\FULL_Backup> Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_basebackup.exe" -ArgumentList "-D G:\FULL_Backup\PG_Basebackup_2022-05-16_085816", "-Ft", "-z", "-R", "-U postgres", "-w" -Wait -NoNewWindow
pg_basebackup: error: could not initiate base backup: ERROR:  could not stat file or directory "./base/18119/43980": Permission denied
pg_basebackup: removing contents of data directory "G:\FULL_Backup\PG_Basebackup_2022-05-16_085816"
```

Thanks,
Udhayan

Comment: It looks like that is an error which occurred on the db server which is just reported back to the client (pg_restore).  Look in the db server's log file to see if there is more info.

Comment: Log file does not have much information                                                             
ERROR:  could not stat file or directory "./base/18119/43980": Permission denied
STATEMENT:  BASE_BACKUP LABEL 'pg_basebackup base backup' PROGRESS   NOWAIT  TABLESPACE_MAP  MANIFEST 'yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database server cannot read one of its own files, which should never happen. You have to fix that condition.

Probably causes for that are:

- You are running a virus scanner on the data directory that locks the file. Don't do that.
- You changed ownership or permissions on that file. You should never modify anything in the data directory.

Comment: hmm ok Laurenz ..let me check if crowdstrike is the cause.  but it was running last week as well that why i am surprised.

Comment: If it is a virus scanner, the problem would be intermittent.